# Is there a way to use off sheet connectors in a hierarchical design within Altium?

Tags: altium

I'm running into a situation where I am running out of space on each sheet I have for a design. I can't increase the sheet size because when I print off the design, the contents would be too small.

I have a top level sheet with multiple off sheet connectors. However, one of those sheets (under the top level sheet), I need to add more components and there just isnt enough space without it getting messy. So I'd like to use off sheet connectors to expand horizontally rather than vertically, however, I am running into an error when I compile which says that there are two top level sheets.

Is there a way to use off sheet connectors in a hierarchical design or a way to tell Altium or a setting or option that says I can do both vertical and horizontal connectivity ?

Answer (score 1):

With Altium, if you're using a hierarchical design you will always have a single top sheet. Yet, why not simply add another sheet to the top sheet. We do you want to use Off-Sheet connectors instead of ports and connect the two sheets to each other.

---

### Addition

[image: SH1]
[image: SH2]
[image: Top Sheet]

This way you can put various parts to multiple sheets. The sheets are only connected using their ports which also helps with explaining the data flow (what is required where).

Comment: Didn't understand the last sentence. Could you reclarify ?

Comment: I think what Tom was saying was that with this hierarchical method you can have one schematic sheet per IC or sub-circuit.  That's often done to clean up complex designs, the top level sheet looks like a block diagram, the port connections are your major interfaces. For example, a Bluetooth module might have lots of associated passives, an antenna, maybe a regulator, but all you care about from the microcontroller page is the interface to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. (thanks to https://www.eevblog.com/forum/altium/altium-offsheet-connector-poorly-docummented/ )

On a higher hierarchy level, create a symbol sheet and modify the "File name" with all your schematics files you want to group, name are separated by "; ".
Now Off sheet connectors should work between these sheets. :)

[image]

Synchronisation with all the sheets works well too.